# To run playbook based on ansible_distribution

Tags: ansible, configuration-management

I have written separate playbooks for  tomcat deployment on both Ubuntu and Linux as well, instead of mentioning  **

> **when: ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu'**

**in every line in the playbook, i want to run the whole playbook only when this condition meets.

This is my code

```
 - hosts: all
   tasks:
      - name: including the playbook for ubuntu deployment
        include: tomcat_ubuntu_new.yaml
        when: ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu'

      - name: including the playbook for ubuntu deployment
        include: tomcat_standalone.yaml
        when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS' or ansible_distribution == 'RedHat'
```

Error:

```
ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'>

The error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/tomcat_ubuntu_new.yaml': line 3, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- hosts: all
  ^ here
```

I want to run the playbook only on the hosts based on the ansible_distribution

I tried many ways but no one works can any one post a clear answer with explanation

Comment: it complains about the included file `/etc/ansible/tomcat_ubuntu_new.yaml`, i would inspect that file too.

Comment: @ilias-sp but i run both playbooks individually it ran fine, many time i ran those playbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"I want to run the playbook only on the hosts based on the ansible_distribution."*

A: It's not possible to *include* a playbook. This would run the playbooks recursively.

Only *import* of a playbook is available. Moreover [import_playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/import_playbook_module.html#import-playbook-import-a-playbook) is not a task. It's simply a tool to modularize large playbooks with multiple plays.

Ansible [conditionals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals) do not apply to `import_playbook` the same way as they do not apply to playbooks.

Instead, it is possible to create a group that will be used in the playbook.

```
$cat tomcat_ubuntu_new.yaml
---
- hosts: my_dynamic_group
  tasks:
  ...
```

For example, let's create the group and import the playbook

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        groups: my_dynamic_group
      loop: "{{ groups.all }}"
      when: hostvars[item].ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu'
      run_once: true

- import_playbook: tomcat_ubuntu_new.yaml
```

Comment: this was not working.. i created the group and imported those playbooks as you mentioned but that did'nt work at all @Vladimir Botka

Comment: I've fixed it. Sorry for the noise.